# how does pickle know which to pick?

Tags: python, pickle

I have my pickle function working properly

```
    with open(self._prepared_data_location_scalar, 'wb') as output:
        # company1 = Company('banana', 40)
        pickle.dump(X_scaler, output, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
        pickle.dump(Y_scaler, output, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)


    with open(self._prepared_data_location_scalar, 'rb') as input_f:
        X_scaler = pickle.load(input_f)
        Y_scaler = pickle.load(input_f)
```

However, I am very curious how does pickle know which to load? Does it mean that everything has to be in the same sequence?

Comment: Pickle is just a serializer.  So objects are pickled [serially](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/serially).

Comment: json is also just a serializer... but this will break horribly ... so acting like this is standard serialization behaviour is wrong. it is a very unique feature of a very unique serializer

Comment: The serialized representation has object boundaries.  Not so for JSON.  My point was that all pickle does is create a bytestring representation, and `pickle.dump(...)` may as well be `open_file.write(pickle.dumps(...))`, so of course they come in/out sequentially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wow I did not even know you could do this ... and I have been using python for a very long time... so thats totally awesome in my book,  however you really should not do this it will be very hard to work with later(especially if it isnt you working on it)

I would recommend just doing

```
pickle.dump({"X":X_scalar,"Y":Y_scalar},output)

 ...
data = pickle.load(fp)
print "Y_scalar:",data['Y']
print "X_scalar:",data['X']
```

unless you have a **very** compelling reason to save and load the data like you were in your question ...

## edit to answer the actual question...

it loads from the start of the file to the end (ie it loads them in the same order they were dumped)

Comment: I see, if I dump in the way you suggested, could you tell me how do we load?

Comment: as an aside ... pickle is an inherintly dangerous construct in python(allows an untrusted user to execute arbitrary code) ... (and its very slow compared to json)

Comment: please add a comment for the downvote... (or be a jerk and dont...)

Comment: Your answer shows a misunderstanding of how serialization works.  There is nothing wrong with OP code, and packing everything in a dict just adds unnecessary overhead.

Comment: well I can respect that .... I just didnt know that when you did pickle load it would stop at the end of each pickle object seperately.... (and i still say this is bad practice and if someone did this inproduction code without a very good reason(ie the data is too big to load all at once reasonably) I would never approve that merge request...)

Comment: Is everything you haven't [yet] encountered automatically "bad practice"?  It's a documented feature.

Comment: no of coarse not (but just because its documented does not make it an appropriate use either... this just seems like it would be a big pain to maintain...)... pickling in general is bad practice though imho (but thats really a seperate deal all together ... )

Comment: Joran: I would have to agree with @wim. What I find astonishing is that you didn't already know it.

Comment: lol I know ... (maybe i did know about it and managed to forget it because it wasnt something i used or could even think of a good use case for) ... to be fair I tend to avoid pickle in general (I know its only dangerous if you have untrusted data comming into it etc... simplejson is orders of magnitude faster and I dont really need to save a python class instance)

Answer (score 6):

What you have is fine.  It's a [documented feature](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickle.Pickler) of pickle:

> It is possible to make multiple calls to the dump() method of the same Pickler instance. These must then be matched to the same number of calls to the load() method of the corresponding Unpickler instance.

There is no magic here, pickle is a really simple stack-based language that serializes python objects into bytestrings.  The pickle format knows about object boundaries: by design, `pickle.dumps('x') + pickle.dumps('y')` is not the same bytestring as `pickle.dumps('xy')`.

If you're interested to learn some background on the implementation, [this article](http://peadrop.com/blog/2007/06/18/pickle-an-interesting-stack-language/) is an easy read to shed some light on the python pickler.

Comment: I don't get this part: *"If the same object is pickled by multiple dump() calls, the load() will all yield references to the same object."* Multiple loads will return multiple instances with the same contents. Thay meant that, surely?

Comment: no they mean `A=B=SomeClass()` both A and B point at the same instance of SomeClass

Answer (score 1):

Yes, pickle pick objects in order of saving.

Intuitively, pickle append to the end when it write (dump) to a file,
and read (load) sequentially the content from a file.

Consequently, order is preserved, allowing you to retrieve your data in the exact order you serialize it.

Comment: but this is probably really really bad practice in general ... but yeah it answers the question imho so +1

Comment: I don't agree with that. Pickle is a converter to *streams*, that are by design FIFO containers. Pickle append content to the file, which is the behavior expected. Wim's answer provides the [documentation reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickle.Pickler).

Comment: the reason I think its bad practice is that say they realize someone has replaced the pickled file with a malicious one, so they change to json(or yaml... or any other serializer) for security(or speed) and bam... all of a sudden everything is busted (and raising exceptions about extra lines) ... where as if they would have stored it as a dict or even a list instead it would work pretty seamlessly by just `s/pickle/json`

Comment: Not necessarily so.  Many things are pickle-able that are not json serializable.  You can't just swap out a serializer willy-nilly, consider for example `d = {0: 'zero', '0': 'zero'}` and compare and contrast the output of `json.loads(json.dumps(d))` with `pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(d))`

Comment: ok good point :) there are lots of things that cannot be json serialized that pickle can serialize ...